# Re-encode from h264 to h265 is possible without config only to reducing the size is possible?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using `ffmpeg` is possible only change the **encode** from `h264` to `h265` without any configuration like `-crf` and `-maxrate` like:

```
for %%a in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    
)
```

For the sole purpose of reducing the size of the final file without changing the quality of the movie/anime.

Comment: have you tested it?

Answer (score 2):

Converting from one lossy codec to another **always** loses data. They are not an evolution where you can apply better compression, they are completely different codec that work in very different ways. As a result the frames are completely decoded and then re-encoded.

Converting from h.264 to h.265 will result in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) even if you try to keep the same "quality".

If you don't want to lose quality then leave your files as is. If you need better quality in a smaller size then you need to convert using higher quality original masters.

You can change the *container* such as `mkv` or `mp4` without losing data. If you are using a particularly inefficient container format then you might save a small amount of space that way, but it is going to be insignificant compared to the size of the video data itself (codec).